# ctable and siunitx: Last column does not center correctly (possible incompatibility?)

Tags: tables, siunitx, columns, ctable

I would like to use `ctable` in my thesis for tables and graphics and I also would like to use `siunitx` for formatting numbers and aligning numbers on the decimal marker in tables.

Everything seemed to work well until I discovered some strange behaviour in the last column. The heading does not get centered there (I tried the different settings for `siunitx`: table-alignment, table-text-alignment, in the preamble and for the specific column). It did not help.

ctable version is rev 26694, v 1.23;

siunitx is rev 29017, v 2.5p

This is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

% Does not center the heading in the last column.
\ctable[]{
  |l
  |S
  |S
  |S|
}{}{
  \FL
  &         {Tom} &     {Suzy} &    {Rob} \ML
  Eating &      122.5 &     1.025 &     1.5 \NN
  Sleeping &    9.1 &       1346.5 &    213.7 \NN
  Working &     7.5 &       9.5 &       2.0125 \NN
  Watching TV & 5.25 &      117.5 &     7.5 \LL}

% Works fine with simple tabular
\begin{tabular}{
  |l
  |S
  |S
  |S|
  }
  \hline
  &         {Tom} &     {Suzy} &    {Rob} \\ \hline
  Eating &      122.5 &     1.025 &     1.5 \\
  Sleeping &    9.1 &       1346.5 &    213.7 \\
  Working &     7.5 &       9.5 &       2.0125 \\
  Watching TV & 5.25 &      117.5 &     7.5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks to me:

[image: ctable and tabular]

Comment: Interesting... A simple fix is adding an empty last column by changing the `|S|` to `|S|@{}l@{}`, and the changing `{Rob} \ML` to `{Rob} &\ML`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It's a known problem, I believe: an `S` column needs to see either & or \\ to know where it ends and `\ML` is not good when there's `\multicolumn`. I tried to find an answer by Joseph Wright, but didn't find it.

Comment: rather than change the preamble you can just change `\ML` to `\tabularnewline \midrule` which is the same thing, but works

Comment: Thank you, too!

I was too quick in hitting Enter on my last comment (and too slow in editing it). So here the rest of my text: It seems to work just fine with `&`, \\ and with \\tabularnewline. I will use those commands together with the original booktabs-commands in the future. To me those are easier to read and remember anyway. Problem solved :-) But to mark it as such it would net an answer, right?

Comment: @user26865 Don't use vertical rules; the table will immediately improve

Comment: Thanks. I only used them to visualize the problem better. I probably should have said so. Usually I do not use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to close off the solution in the comments

Rather than change the preamble you can just change `\ML` to `\tabularnewline \midrule` which is the same thing, but works.