# Alignment in siunitx table

Tags: tables, siunitx

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE,
  detect-weight = true,
  detect-inline-weight = math,
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 1
]{siunitx}

\def\mlrA{1ex}
\def\mlrB{\hspace{0.5em}}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% constants
\def\masse{80}
\def\Jorden{9.8}
\def\Maanen{1.6}
\def\Juliper{26.5}
\def\Pluto{0.3}
\def\Mars{3.8}
\def\Venus{8.8}
\def\Merkur{5.4}
\def\Neptun{11.0}
\def\Uranus{10.4}
\def\Saturn{11.3}

\begin{center}
\large
 \begin{tabular}{
        |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm}
   *{3}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}}|
 }
  \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Planet}}
  &                      \textbf{Tyngdekraften p{\aa} \SI{1}{\kg}}
  &                      \textbf{Tyngdekraften p{\aa} personen}
  &        \vspace{0.5ex}\textbf{Svarer til Jordens tr{\ae}k i}                                                              \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Jorden  & \mlrB\SI{\Jorden}{\N}  &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Månen   & \mlrB\SI{\Maanen}{\N}  &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Jupiter &      \SI{\Juliper}{\N} &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Pluto   & \mlrB\SI{\Pluto}{\N}   &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Mars    & \mlrB\SI{\Mars}{\N}    &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Venus   & \mlrB\SI{\Venus}{\N}   &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Merkur  & \mlrB\SI{\Merkur}{\N}  & \SI{\calc{\masse*\Merkur}}{\N} & \saenk{\SI{\calc{\masse*\Merkur/\Jorden}}{\kg}} \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Neptun  &      \SI{\Neptun}{\N}  &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Uranus  &      \SI{\Uranus}{\N}  &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Saturn  &      \SI{\Saturn}{\N}  &                                &                                                 \\[\mlrA]
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I *automatically* align the units (`N`) and the corresponding numbers in the second column of the table?

I've had a look at the code for [table 49 in the `siunitx` manual](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf#page=72) but couldn't make it work. Therefore I've removed the `S`-column again in the table code, in order to make it look correct.

Comment: I am little bit lost: What do you mean with automatically? Like the `S` column specification allows you to do? But with units? Why the [tag:vertical-alignment] tag? Also: Why not put the unit in the table header? (One might argument that this is a better way …) Why not even N/kg in the second column?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Automatically: yes, like the `S`-column specification allows for. Unit in table header: I'm teaching people how are not used to this, but normally I would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `table-space-text-pos` and the `<` column specification.

For some reason, the last column acts up with `S` and `<` which seems to be related with the problems in [ctable and siunitx: Last column does not center correctly (possible incompatibility?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100925). I have found that adding another column at the end helps,
see also [Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill)'s
[comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100925/ctable-and-siunitx-last-column-does-not-center-correctly-possible-incompatibil#comment218844_100925).

If you change `\mlrA` to `.5ex` you can replace the first column with

```
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr1em+.5ex}}b{2.4cm}
```

you don't need macros like `\saenk`.

You can even get rid of `\mlrA` itself if you use something like

```
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{\dimexpr1em+2ex}}b{2.4cm}
```

(These measurements aren't the same that produces your vertical spacing but you get the idea.)

However, this does not help in the case of actual multi-line cells as those in the header because they are treated by TeX as one character on a single line and they add more height than their single-line companions of the same row.
You will need to include another special strut at least for the tallest header.

The result of that is in Code B below. I also changed all multi-line column specifications to `b` as they `b`ottom-align vertically.

### Code

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE,
  detect-weight = true,
  detect-inline-weight = math,
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 1
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}

\def\mlrA{1ex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \newcommand*\siunitxNumberUnitProduct{\l__siunitx_number_unit_product_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\masse{80}
\def\Jorden{9.8}
\def\Maanen{1.6}
\def\Juliper{26.5}
\def\Pluto{0.3}
\def\Mars{3.8}
\def\Venus{8.8}
\def\Merkur{5.4}
\def\Neptun{11.0}
\def\Uranus{10.4}
\def\Saturn{11.3}

\begin{center}
\large
\begin{tabular}{
 |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm}
 |S[table-format = 2.1,
    table-space-text-post = \siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\N}]<{\siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\N}}
 |S[table-format = 3.0,
    table-space-text-post = \siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\N}]<{\siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\N}}
 |S[table-format = 3.1,
    table-space-text-post = \siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\kg}]<{\siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\kg}}
 |@{}c@{} % something's fishy with S in the last column
}
\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Planet}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{4cm}|}{\textbf{Tyngdekraften p{\aa} \SI{1}{\kg}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{4cm}|}{\textbf{Tyngdekraften p{\aa} personen}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{4cm}|}{\textbf{Svarer til Jordens tr{\ae}ki}}  \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Jorden  & \Jorden  & \fpeval{\masse*\Jorden} & \fpeval{\masse*\Jorden/\Jorden} & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Månen   & \Maanen  & \fpeval{\masse*\Maanen} & \fpeval{\masse*\Maanen/\Jorden} & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Jupiter & \Juliper & \fpeval{\masse*\Juliper}& \fpeval{\masse*\Juliper/\Jorden}& \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Pluto   & \Pluto   & \fpeval{\masse*\Pluto}  & \fpeval{\masse*\Pluto/\Jorden}  & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Mars    & \Mars    & \fpeval{\masse*\Mars}   & \fpeval{\masse*\Mars/\Jorden}   & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Venus   & \Venus   & \fpeval{\masse*\Venus}  & \fpeval{\masse*\Venus/\Jorden}  & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Merkur  & \Merkur  & \fpeval{\masse*\Merkur} & \fpeval{\masse*\Merkur/\Jorden} & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Neptun  & \Neptun  & \fpeval{\masse*\Neptun} & \fpeval{\masse*\Neptun/\Jorden} & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Uranus  & \Uranus  & \fpeval{\masse*\Uranus} & \fpeval{\masse*\Uranus/\Jorden} & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline Saturn  & \Saturn  & \fpeval{\masse*\Saturn} & \fpeval{\masse*\Saturn/\Jorden} & \\[\mlrA]
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Code B

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE,
  detect-weight = true,
  detect-inline-weight = math,
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 1
]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \newcommand*\siunitxNumberUnitProduct{\l__siunitx_number_unit_product_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\masse{80}
\def\Jorden{9.8}
\def\Maanen{1.6}
\def\Juliper{26.5}
\def\Pluto{0.3}
\def\Mars{3.8}
\def\Venus{8.8}
\def\Merkur{5.4}
\def\Neptun{11.0}
\def\Uranus{10.4}
\def\Saturn{11.3}

\newcommand*\myStrut{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{\dimexpr1em+2ex}}
\newcommand*\myStrutH{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr1em+.5ex}}

\begin{center}
\large
\begin{tabular}{
 |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\myStrut}b{2.4cm}
 |S[table-format = 2.1,
    table-space-text-post = \siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\N}]<{\siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\N}}
 |S[table-format = 3.0,
    table-space-text-post=\siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\N}]<{\siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\N}}
 |S[table-format = 3.1,
    table-space-text-post=\siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\kg}]<{\siunitxNumberUnitProduct\si{\kg}}
 |@{}c@{} % something's fishy with S in the last column
}
  \hline\multicolumn{1}{|>\myStrut c|}{\textbf{Planet}}
      & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\myStrutH}b{4cm}|}{\textbf{Tyngdekraften p{\aa} \SI{1}{\kg}}}
      & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}b{4cm}|}{\textbf{Tyngdekraften p{\aa} personen}}
      & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}b{4cm}|}{\textbf{Svarer til Jordens tr{\ae}ki}}  \\
  \hline Jorden  & \Jorden  & \calc{\masse*\Jorden} & \calc{\masse*\Jorden/\Jorden} & \\
  \hline Månen   & \Maanen  & \calc{\masse*\Maanen} & \calc{\masse*\Maanen/\Jorden} & \\
  \hline Jupiter & \Juliper & \calc{\masse*\Juliper}& \calc{\masse*\Juliper/\Jorden}& \\
  \hline Pluto   & \Pluto   & \calc{\masse*\Pluto}  & \calc{\masse*\Pluto/\Jorden}  & \\
  \hline Mars    & \Mars    & \calc{\masse*\Mars}   & \calc{\masse*\Mars/\Jorden}   & \\
  \hline Venus   & \Venus   & \calc{\masse*\Venus}  & \calc{\masse*\Venus/\Jorden}  & \\
  \hline Merkur  & \Merkur  & \calc{\masse*\Merkur} & \calc{\masse*\Merkur/\Jorden} & \\
  \hline Neptun  & \Neptun  & \calc{\masse*\Neptun} & \calc{\masse*\Neptun/\Jorden} & \\
  \hline Uranus  & \Uranus  & \calc{\masse*\Uranus} & \calc{\masse*\Uranus/\Jorden} & \\
  \hline Saturn  & \Saturn  & \calc{\masse*\Saturn} & \calc{\masse*\Saturn/\Jorden} & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Really great. Now, the only problem is that the physical quantities are at the top of each cell and not vertically centered inside them.

Comment: Ah, yeah, ... I deleted the use of `\saenk` and didn't understand why you used it. Why the `\mlrA` anyway? Easiest would be to half the `\mlrA` and add a strut with proper dimensions with `>` to the first column.

Comment: Can I make you add the things you are talking about in the comment? I've tried myself and falied. `:-(`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I edited my answer. I wouldn't use that many horizontal and no vertical lines anyway (Hint: `booktabs`), but you talked about teaching people what not to do, so …